# Could a slow website cause visitors from a Facebook ads campaign to bounce?

Tags: google-analytics, advertising, performance, bounce

I have a website with traffic problems.
The web site sells a product in Spanish.

I recently created a Facebook ads campaign,
and it got 96 visits.
But Google Analytics only registered 9 visits.
I think my website could be slow and people are bouncing. Could this be the case?

I am using Wordpress and the Profitbuiler plugin to create the page.

Comment: Can you edit your question to tell us *why* you think it may be slow? Are you measuring this? Does Google report slow pages on your site?

Answer (score 1):

This could very well be the case. I expect that facebook counts clicking on a link as a visit, but for GA to count the visit the page first needs to be rendered and then the code referencing run/hit.   If a page has a slow tome to first bite this could cause users to close the page rather then waiting and could explain the discrepancy.

Another possibility is the GA code has not been correctly implemented or (unlikely) your users are overwhelmingly using privacy/ad blockers.